# export classes and function in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

In my angularJS I have seperate JS file wherein prototype functions are declared like below:

```
function lastConversation(){
 this.item1="1"
 this.message="test"
......

}
lastConversation.prototype.setupfromMessageThread(data) {
  this.currentBox = data.currentBox ||  null;
  data.internalId = data.internalId ||  null;
  this.addParticipants(data.participants);
}

lastConversation.prototype.addParticipants = function (participants) {
}
```

I wanted to similar stuff in angular 6 and created class

```
export class conversation {

constructor(json?: any) {
    if (!json) return;
   this.item=json.internalId || 0;
  }

 setupfromMessageThread(conversation) {
    this.internalId = conversation.internalId || null; }}
```

However when in my ts file when I use

```
lastconveration = new dataModel.Conversation()
lastconveration.setupfromMessageThread(conversation)
```

it says setupfromMessageThread is not function. if I wanted to use same angularJs function do I need to use export before each function or in case of angular6 what I am missing.

Comment: Have you gone through with angular.io to see how class and all is made in Angular?

Comment: could you please reproduce it on stackblitz? everything looks fine from current question description

Comment: I want to know How it is to convert prototype based inheritance in vanilla javascript to angular6.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing this:

```
lastconveration = new dataModel.Conversation(); 
lastconveration.setupfromMessageThread(conversation);
```

> **Just call your method using `this`**

```
this.setupfromMessageThread(conversation)
```

Comment: the functions are part of other file

Comment: Then put that function in the service and then import that service and call method.

Comment: If I were to use same vanila javascript function  & prototype functions I need to put it in export before each function ?

Answer (score 0):

To express the `lastConversation` function as a class:

```
class LastConverstion { 
    constructor(){
        this.item1="1"
        this.message="test"
         //......
    }

    setupfromMessageThread(data) {
      this.currentBox = data.currentBox ||  null;
      data.internalId = data.internalId ||  null;
      this.addParticipants(data.participants);
    }
    
    addParticipants (participants) {
    }
}
```

It is common practice to capitilize the name of classes.

### Usage

```
let instance = new LastConversation();
```